# Create a Stream from an EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to create a stream so that I can use a function from https://github.com/bbc/slayer#streaming-detection

I am trying to take events in from a bluetooth device, which is working. i can save them or write them in any way, but I need to "pipe" them to this library.

I'd prefer not to call `fromArray` each time, or `Arrays.stream(..)`.

I have tried calling `emit`,`write`,`read`.

On inspection the `slayer.createReadStream` returns the following in inspector:

> Object
>   _destroyed: false
>
> _events: {}
>
> _readableState: {objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 16, buffer: {head: null, tail: null, length: 0}, length: 0, pipes: null, …}
>
> _transformState: {needTransform: false, transforming: false, writecb: null, writechunk: null, writeencoding: null}
>
> _writableState: {objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 16, finalCalled: false, needDrain: false, ending: false, …}
>
> allowHalfOpen: true
>
> readable: true
>
> writable: true

I could not find any functions? I am very confused.

Comment: According to the docs, the streams are actually plain Node readable streams. So  you can simply create a [Node Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), emit the `data` event whenever you have something and compose your logic.

Comment: Would I just write "pipe" from the readable to the readable and then emit to my own readable stream when an event occurs?

Comment: Pretty much: you'd define a `someStream` and then copy the `someStream` example snippet to integrate with Slayer.